# Salesforce - How to compare two Date/Time fields?

Tags: formula-field, datetime

Good afternoon!

I am working on a formula field that will compare two DATE/TIME fields and return the larger of the two dates. My current formula is drafted below, but so far, the field I am trying to populate remains blank. Is there as specific way to correctly compare two Date/Time fields?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please [edit] your question to include your current formula as text rather than an image. Text is more accessible, and it makes it a lot easier to help you format it so that it's readable and for answers to suggest modifications. Otherwise, people are going to have to type it out explicitly (and the more work you make people do, the fewer people are going to be willing to help).

Comment: For now, the first thing I can remark on is that using `CASE()` here is probably a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as an odd way to use the `CASE()` function. I think the issue here is that you're trying to make a "dynamic formula". Something where the actual formula isn't known until "run time" (i.e. when you query or view a record's detail page).

Formulas are compiled once, and that happens when you click "save" when creating a formula field (and including in flows, validation rules, approval processes, etc... are pretty similar).

So, Salesforce isn't able to handle such "dynamic formulas". It may or may not give you an error when you try to save the formula, but such things will have undefined behavior.

You'll need to get rid of that `CASE()` and stick to a more traditional nested `IF()` structure

In general, when working on dates:

- The normal comparison operators (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `=`, and `<>`/`!=`) do work on dates
- when doing any comparison against a null value (i.e. a blank field), the result will be false

If you don't need to worry about potential null values, then it's as simple as

```java
IF(
    Date1 > Date2,
    /* Date1 is greater */
    Date1,
    /* Date2 is greater _or equal_ */
    /* In the equal case, Date2 is also a valid choice, so we use Date2 */
    Date2
)
```

Handling null values is a bit trickier, but the `BLANKVALUE()` function can help with that; allowing us to default to, say, 1900-01-01. From there, we can use simple comparisons without the fear of getting a false negative (or rather, an incorrect `false` from the comparison)

```java
IF(
    /* We need to handle the "both are blank" scenario first */
    ISBLANK(Date1) && ISBLANK(Date2),
    null,
    IF(
        /* Since we handled the "both are blank" scenario in the outer IF */
        /* we can only have a maximum of 1 blank date in this inner IF */
        /* BLANKVALUE() in conjunction with a comparison is able to handle */
        /*   a single blank date */ 
        BLANKVALUE(Date1, DATE(1900, 1, 1)) > BLANKVALUE(Date2, DATE(1900, 1, 1)),
        Date1,
        Date2
    )
)
```